# Delphi 7 prescience of class helpers

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, helper, reserved-words

Today I happened to compile, using Delphi 7, a code with a class definition like this

```
type TAudioStream = class helper of TStream;
```

and, to my astonishment, the compiler spits

*"System unit out of date or corrupted: missing 'TClassHelperBase'"*.

It looks like Delphi7 has already some reserved usage of the `helper` word.

Delphi introduced Helper classes in Delphi 8. They were intended for binding VCL to .Net. So, is Delphi7 prescient?

Comment: I wonder if you edit the system unit to include TClassHelperBase, will it compile, maybe the compilercode is already in, but the RTL-implementation did not make the deadline.

Comment: Sorry; have to vote to close this as "not a real question". "Is Delphi7 prescient?" isn't a real (or answerable) question related to programming, and a discussion about how compilers/languages reserve words for the future is off-topic and should be on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Delphi 7 included the ".Net preview compiler." Delphi 7 was aware of some upcoming features, and evidently, it was even somewhat aware of the implementation of those features — it knew enough to expect certain things to be in the System unit and to complain when they weren't present.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this a real question. Reservation of keywords for future implementation is a common practice. The roadmap and the planned features for Delphi 8 should be specified at the release date of Delphi 7. So yes, I think Delphi 7 is prescient in this case.

Comment: I think the question would better be "reserving words not implemented, is it common practice?" and in that case "such a wretch error message (*System unit out of date or corrupted*)  shouldn't be considered as a compiler bug?"

Answer (score 1):

It is quite common for language designers to reserve certain words for future use. `class` and `interface`, for example, have been reserved words in JavaScript for … what, ten years now … even though they aren't expected to be used for another couple of years. `goto` is a reserved word in Java, even though it is *never* expected to be used.

It is also quite common for compiler writers to implement features for future use. Generics, for example, were already implemented in Sun's Java 1.2 `javac` compiler, even though they weren't added to the language specification until Java 5.

Comment: helper doesn't have to be a (globally) reserved word, since it has a fixed relation with "class" (always follows it in some predictable order). So I think this is not a reservation but already a symptom of the eventual implementation, maybe partially disabled